# Python: mysterious skipping first item in list?

Tags: python

I have a 3D list `haaros_seforim` and I am just iterating over it in order to check the contents.

```
for sindex, sefer in enumerate(haaros_seforim):
    for hindex, haarah in enumerate(sefer):
        for pindex, paragraph in enumerate(haarah):
            print "INDEX\/ "+str(sindex)+" "+str(hindex)+" "+str(pindex)
            print paragraph
```

But oddly enough, it seems that for the second-D we're starting from the second item, or index-1:

```
INDEX\/ 0 1 0
[...contents...]
INDEX\/ 0 2 0
[...contents...]
```

In fact, it seems this is happening for the nest two items too (`1 1 0` and `2 1 0`), then for the fourth normal (`3 0 0`), and the fifth and final skips two (`4 2 0`).

I tried sticking in a filter for good measure, and this didn't seem to help:

```
filter(lambda(x): x is not None, ...)
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Could you post what you're iterating over (or something similar) so we can recreate the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
You've done well with the brevity, but we need enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe the first `haarah` is empty.

Comment: @user2357112 if this was the case I'd just see a blank line, not nothing.

Comment: Why would you see a blank line? Where's the code that would print a blank line when something is empty?

Comment: In which case, can you give an MCVE as Prune suggested?

Comment: @EsterLin No you won't, the for loop won't run any iterations

Comment: @EsterLin: No you wouldn't. Why would you expect a blank line?

Comment: pro-tip: you could just `print "INDEX\/ ", sindex, hindex, pindex`

Comment: @user2357112 was right, I misinterpretred blank as[ ''], but you meant []. This was the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the numbering consecutive even when there are blank items in the list, just use `filter` with the first argument `None` to eliminate any that are falsey:

```
for sindex, sefer in enumerate(haaros_seforim):
    for hindex, haarah in enumerate(sefer):
        for pindex, paragraph in enumerate(filter(None, haarah)):
            print "INDEX\/ "+str(sindex)+" "+str(hindex)+" "+str(pindex)
            print paragraph
```